# Typeof Date Field Shows Text Affinity in sqlite3

Tags: date, sqlite

Take this sqlite3 interactive session:

```
sqlite> create table d(t date);
sqlite> insert into d values('1913-12-23');
sqlite> select t,typeof(t) from d;
1913-12-23|text
sqlite>
```

Why is the date field showing up as type text? Would storage space be smaller and queries be faster if it were numeric?

[Sqlite3 datatype documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) shows that the affinity for date columns is numeric according to the table in §2.2. I would guess that date fields stored as numeric values as opposed to text would take up less space, so that would be ideal. I could very well not have a good grasp of sqlite yet, so my concerns may be invalid.

For easy copy/paste:

```
create table d(t date);
insert into d values('1913-12-23');
select t,typeof(t) from d;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `typeof('1913-12-23')` returns `text` is that `'1913-12-23'` is a string, and is stored in the table as a string.
Type affinity comes into play only when the conversion would be lossless; e.g., the value `'123456'` would be converted into a number.

SQLite does not have a native date data type.
To allow dates to be handled by the [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), you have to store them either as `yyyy-mm-dd` strings or as numbers (either Julian day numbers, or seconds since the Unix epoch).

Integers take up less storage than strings, so queries are faster if the DB's bottleneck is I/O, which is likely.

Comment: Thanks! So, do you suggest that I store either Epoch time as an int or Julian date as a... something, then?

Comment: Yes. (Julian dates without time are integers.)